# How can I replace "some" parameter in GRAPHQL query?

Tags: search, filter, graphql

I've the follow query and I wanna get only one result of siteAttributeValues that will be regarding to search in "variables". What can I use instead of `some` in my query?

```
{
  "query": "query($search: String!) {
    sites (
      take: 10, 
      where: { 
        siteAttributeValues: { 
          some: { 
            stringValue: { 
              like: $search 
            } 
          }
        }
      }
    ) {
      items {
        id
        name
        siteAttributeValues {
          id
          stringValue
        }
      }
    }
  }",
  "variables": {search: "%test-erp2%"}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GraphQL is, despite it's name, *not* a traditional query language. It does not have intrinsic filtering and sorting capabilities.

You'll need to introspect the *schema* of the server your query is targeting to determine what filtering and sorting capabilities it supports. GraphQL servers are typically self-documenting and support introspection by accessing their endpoint from a browser. This exposes a *playground* where you can see all the definitions.

If you are targeting a server at `https://somehost/graphql` for example then just put that url into your browser and browse the schema.

However some GraphQL servers hide this feature for security-by-obscurity reasons. In that case you'll need to look at the server's documentation.